How quantum laws hold on macroscopic level in classical computers?
Disclaimer: I am not sure about whether my question is suitable for here, but I will ask it anyway.
I am making research about quantum cryptography, so I start reading a book. In one paragraph, it is said that

Ordinary computers operate at a relatively macroscopic level, and at
that level quantum laws and classical laws are almost indistinguishable.It did not therefore matter that scientists had generally thought of
ordinary computers in terms of classical physics. However, at the
microscopic level the two sets of laws diverge, and at this level only the laws of quantum physics hold true.

I am confused here, because I know that laws of quantum and classical physics are very different. Can you please enlighten me about the sentence "at that level quantum laws and classical laws are almost indistinguishable".
I could not understand how quantum laws hold in macroscopic level.

As far as we know, reality is fundamentally governed by quantum laws. However, our everyday experience shows that at the macroscopic level it follows the laws of classical mechanics. Therefore, quantum theory must reproduce the laws of classical mechanics in the limit of sufficiently large number of degrees of freedom possessing sufficiently high energy. This relationship between quantum and classical mechanics is sometimes referred to as the correspondence principle.
The parameter ranges in which the two sets of physical laws are practically indistinguishable is sometimes called the correspondence regime. The quote in the question says that classical computers (like most objects we encounter in everyday life) operate in the correspondence regime.
You can find more details in quantum decoherence and in papers by Wojciech Zurek, such as
"Why We Don't Need Quantum Planetary Dynamics".
